# Flutter app can't include debug symbols in android app bundle when abi filters are added

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk

Hi I am trying to include debug debug symbols in android app bundle generated by flutter. But it doesn't include debug symbols. This is my release build configuration. It once worked but after I added abi filters it stopped working.

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
//            multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
//            useProguard true
            ndk {
                debugSymbolLevel 'SYMBOL_TABLE'
                abiFilters 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
            }
        }

    }
```

Here is the complete build.gradle file

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}
def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}
def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}
def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
//CRASHLYTICS
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
//END Crashlytics 

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "it.medory.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 4033
        versionName "1.0.9"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
//            multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
//            useProguard true
            ndk {
                debugSymbolLevel 'SYMBOL_TABLE'
                abiFilters 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
            }
        }

    }

    buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'
    ndkVersion '21.4.7075529'
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0"
//CRASHLYTICS
    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.1')
    // Declare the dependencies for the Crashlytics and Analytics libraries
    // When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
//END CRASHLYTICS
}
```

Any one knows how to include debug symbols in app bundle generated using flutter.